# Is there meant to be an actor framework template in LabVIEW 2017

Tags: labview

I thought there was an Actor framework template that could be launched in LabVIEW 2017.

[image]

Did I get that wrong?  It doesn't seem to be listed in the templates as shown above.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to File-> Create Project, there will be a new Create Project prompt that will have Templates. That is where you will find the Actor Framework Template (its a project), not under New VI Templates.